# Modifying matrix values based on another matrix without using a loop or apply function

Tags: r, matrix, adjacency-matrix

I have two matrices `S` and `A` and I would like to modify values of `A` based on values of `S`. Matrix `S` contains indices of matrix `A` which I would like to modify. For instance

```
S <- matrix(c(2,3,3,1,1,2),nrow=3, byrow=TRUE)

   [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    3
[2,]    3    1
[3,]    1    2
```

The resulting matrix `A` would be

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    1    1
[2,]    1    0    1
[3,]    1    1    0
```

In other words,  In matrix S every row represents a graph vertex. Values in every row (say `i`th) are indices of vertices which are connected to `i`th vertex. Matrix `A` is an adjacency matrix of the graph.

**Question:** How to solve the problem, i.e. obtain matrix `A`, without using a for loop or apply/sapply/mapply etc. functions? What is the fastest way to do this?

EDIT: An example

```
S <- matrix(c(2,3,3,1,1,2,1,2),nrow=4, byrow=TRUE)

    [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    3
[2,]    3    1
[3,]    1    2
[4,]    1    2
```

The result should be:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    1    1    1
[2,]    1    0    1    1
[3,]    1    1    0    0
[4,]    1    1    0    0
```

Comment: In your new example, where is the index for the 4th column?  THe numbers are only till 3

Comment: For the first row, I assume, 2, 3 implies the 'A' would change 0 to 1, but why it is filling for 4th column when there is no index

Comment: @akrun There is a filling because in the 4th row there is 1 in the first column, which means 4th and 1th vertices are connected

Comment: Ok, then the update may help

Comment: what is the purpose of having `1, 2` twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the 'S' as row/column index to change the values in A

```
A <- matrix(0, 4, 4)
A[cbind(c(row(S)), c(S))] <- 1
+(A|t(A))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    0    1    1    1
#[2,]    1    0    1    1
#[3,]    1    1    0    0
#[4,]    1    1    0    0
```

Comment: It doesn't work the way I want it. In matrix S every row represents a graph vertex. Values in every row (say ith) are indices of vertices which are connected to ith vertex. I will make it clearer and edit the question.

Comment: @treskov What is your input 'A' matrix

Comment: A should be an adjacency matrix. Counterexample to your solution: `S <- matrix(c(2,3,3,1,1,2,1,2),nrow=4, byrow=TRUE)`

Comment: @treskov if you could update your post with the example, would be helpful

Comment: Could you please explain what `+(A|t(A))` is? I know `|` is an OR statement and it makes matrix A symmetrical as it should be but I don't understand why it works :) Thanks for the answer

Comment: @treskov I am transposing (`t`) the object and checking if there is any 1 on the transposed elementwise and then coerce it to binary with `+`